# Ruby Pause thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

In ruby, is it possible to cause a thread to pause from a different concurrently running thread.

Below is the code that I've written so far.  I want the user to be able to type 'pause thread' and the sample500 thread to pause.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Creates a new thread executes the block every intervalSec for durationSec.
def DoEvery(thread, intervalSec, durationSec)
    thread = Thread.new do
        start = Time.now

        timeTakenToComplete = 0
        loopCounter = 0
        while(timeTakenToComplete < durationSec && loopCounter += 1)

            yield

            finish = Time.now

            timeTakenToComplete = finish - start

            sleep(intervalSec*loopCounter - timeTakenToComplete)    
        end
    end
end

# User input loop.
exit = nil
while(!exit)
    userInput = gets
    case userInput
    when "start thread\n"
        sample500 = Thread
        beginTime = Time.now
        DoEvery(sample500, 0.5, 30) {File.open('abc', 'a') {|file| file.write("a\n")}}
    when "pause thread\n"
        sample500.stop
    when "resume thread"
        sample500.run
    when "exit\n"
        exit = TRUE
    end
end
```

Comment: "I'm new to Ruby; only been learning it for a few days" - and you're already on threading? That's impressive!

Comment: Haha thanks!  Seems like a really nice language; I love the whole blocks thing and the yielding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing Thread object as argument to `DoEvery` function makes no sense because you immediately overwrite it with Thread.new, check out this modified version:

```
def DoEvery(intervalSec, durationSec)
    thread = Thread.new do
        start = Time.now
        Thread.current["stop"] = false

        timeTakenToComplete = 0
        loopCounter = 0
        while(timeTakenToComplete < durationSec && loopCounter += 1)
            if Thread.current["stop"]
              Thread.current["stop"] = false
              puts "paused"
              Thread.stop
            end

            yield

            finish = Time.now

            timeTakenToComplete = finish - start

            sleep(intervalSec*loopCounter - timeTakenToComplete)

        end
    end
    thread
end

# User input loop.
exit = nil
while(!exit)
    userInput = gets
    case userInput
    when "start thread\n"
        sample500 = DoEvery(0.5, 30) {File.open('abc', 'a') {|file| file.write("a\n")} }
    when "pause thread\n"
        sample500["stop"] = true
    when "resume thread\n"
        sample500.run
    when "exit\n"
        exit = TRUE
    end
end
```

Here `DoEvery` returns new thread object. Also note that Thread.stop called inside running thread, you can't directly stop one thread from another because it is not safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I like how your solution.  There were a few timing issues with it which I have suggested in an edit (just to make the answer complete for anyone else who may come across it).  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to better able to accomplish what you are attempting using [Ruby Fiber](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fiber.html) object, and likely achieve better efficiency on the running system.

> Fibers are primitives for implementing light weight cooperative
>   concurrency in Ruby. Basically they are a means of creating code
>   blocks that can be paused and resumed, much like threads. The main
>   difference is that they are never preempted and that the scheduling
>   must be done by the programmer and not the VM.

Keeping in mind the current implementation of MRI Ruby does not offer *any* concurrent running threads and the best you are able to accomplish is a [*green threaded*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) program, the following is a nice example:

```
require "fiber"

f1 = Fiber.new { |f2| f2.resume Fiber.current; while true; puts "A"; f2.transfer; end }
f2 = Fiber.new { |f1| f1.transfer; while true; puts "B"; f1.transfer; end }

f1.resume f2 # =>
  # A
  # B 
  # A
  # B
  # .
  # .
  # .
```